# Use OR/ AND Operator Between Two GPIO on python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am writing a short program in Python on raspberryPi, to stop while loop by any of one GPIO from two, but it is not stopping the loop although if I use GPIO individually its successfully work.

My both GPIO(23) and GPIO(24) are working fine,

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(23,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(24,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)

while (GPIO.input(23) or GPIO.input(24)) == True:
    print ("Loop")

print ("Stop")
```

Can you please guide me on how do i resolve this issue?

Comment: check these codes 
`while any([GPIO.input(23), GPIO.input(24)]):
        print ("Loop")`

Comment: @Fahadkalis it's start working